# Looking for Metadata on Terdata Tables pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl and pdcrinfo.dbqlogtbl

Tags: teradata

I have searched and searched the web and the TD forums, and have not had luck locating the Metadata (column definitions) for the two Performance Usage Tables below.

```
pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl 
pdcrinfo.dbqlogtbl
```

Does anyone happen to be familiar with these and where I can find that information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBQL-tables in PDCRDATA are mostly copies of the tables in DBC (besides the added `LOGDATE` partitioning column) and in PDCRINFO there 1:1-views simply selecting all columns.

So all the metadata can be found in the manuals covering DBQL, e.g. for TD15.00: [Tracking Query Behavior with Database Query Logging](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/Database_Management/B035_1093_015K/1093Chap16.040.01.html)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Dieter said, you may probably just focus on DBC database, and the query below would suffice in most cases (in this example hits for the past 12 hours):

```
 Select unique
   , UserName
   , ObjectDatabaseName
   , ObjectTableName
   , StatementType
 From  DBC.DBQLogTbl dbqlogtbl
 ,     DBC.DBQLObjTbl  dbqlobjtbl
 Where 1=1
 and      dbqlobjtbl.ProcID   =  dbqlogtbl.ProcID
 and      dbqlobjtbl.QueryID  =  dbqlogtbl.QueryID
 and      dbqlogtbl.CollectTimeStamp between
       (dbqlobjtbl.CollectTimeStamp  -  Interval '12' Hour)
       and
       Current_Timestamp(0)
--
  and ObjectTableName is not null
```